# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsrangeexception

So I have a UITableView, and the app crashes with this error every time that the array does not have any items in it. What is strange is that I have another table that does not crash when it has zero objects in the array, and I am using almost identical code for each.  Here is what I have:

```
@implementation FindFBFriendsViewController {
    NSMutableArray *friends;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UserFBFriends *fbFriends = [UserFBFriends sharedInstance];
    NSLog(@"Hell0 from the fbfriends view, array is %@", fbFriends.userFriends);
    friends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fbFriends.userFriends];

    IndFBFriend *testFriend = [friends objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"USER Friends:    %@", testFriend.fullName);
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.fbTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [friends count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     FBFriendCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"friendCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FBFriendCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    IndFBFriend *indexRowFriend = [friends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell updateCellWithName:indexRowFriend.fullName profilePicture:indexRowFriend.profPic personFBId:indexRowFriend.fbId];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Here is the stack:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106213d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010597adeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001060f1804 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 212
    3   gif-wrap                            0x000000010338dd24 -[FindFBFriendsViewController viewDidLoad] + 340
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010421b984 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010422193b -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 120
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000104251750 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1203
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000104261b9b -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000104262d0b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104411503 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010413b980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109754c00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010974908e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109748f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010973d3c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010976b086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010407b72e _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7135
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106139301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010612f22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010612e6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010612e0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000109204ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000104080f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    23  gif-wrap                            0x00000001033922ef main + 111
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010752892d start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say yourself that this happens when the friends array is empty. What do you expect to see when you run the following:

```
IndFBFriend *testFriend = [friends objectAtIndex:0];
```

[`-[NSArray objectAtIndex:]` throws an exception when you access an index that does not exist](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1417555-objectatindex?language=objc); when `friends` is empty, that's what you see. Index 0 is invalid for an empty array.

You haven't posted your other code, but I'm guessing that your other code does not contain a line like this, so it does not crash.

Comment: Hah thanks for pointing that out. I added that NSLog statement earlier to test, completely forgot to take it out.

Comment: In general, if you see an exception, take a look at the associated message, because it is usually helpful. In this case you already knew that this was happening during access of an empty array, but there are two hints for you to look at: `-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]:` indicates that the crash is happening at an `-objectAtIndex:` (so audit where you call `-objectAtIndex:` yourself), but more importantly, if you look at the backtrace, you can see that the crash is due to `-objectAtIndex:` in your `-viewDidLoad` (call stack lines 2 and 3). There's only one in there, so that's the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use `IndFBFriend *testFriend = [friends firstObject];` which is safer.